# Codeigniter SMTP Email Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, zoho

I can't get my emails to send when using SMTP with my codeigniter app.

There are many similar questions on SO, but none that solve my problem so that's why I'm asking again.

Here's the error i'm getting:

```
hello: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 22:54:12 -0400
From: 
Return-Path: 
To: myemail@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Request_from_C&J_Builders_Contact_form?=
Reply-To: "donotreply@C&JBuilders.us" 
X-Sender: donotreply@C&JBuilders.us
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <53572b54551be@C&JBuilders.us>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

From: jeff
Email: jeff@gmail.com
Phone: 555555555
Message: asdfs fds

Here's my config/email.php:
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['_smtp_auth']   = TRUE;
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.zoho.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "donotreply@cjbuilders.info";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "mypassword";
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76;
$config['mailtype'] = "text";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = TRUE;
$config['bcc_batch_size'] = "200";

?>
```

Here's my controller snippet that sends the email:

```
// sends the email to 
$this->email->from('donotreply@C&JBuilders.us');
$this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Request from C&amp;J Builders Contact form');
$this->email->message('From: '.$this->input->post('name')."\n".
              'Email: '.$this->input->post('email')."\n".
              'Phone: '.$this->input->post('phone')."\n".
              'Message: '.$this->input->post('message')."\n");
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: try adding the config `$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';` its not on the official docs, some SMTP server requires ssl authentication.

Comment: Doesn't do anything different. This page says that zoho DOES require ssl https://www.zoho.com/mail/faq.html

Comment: it says SSL on the link you gave me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SSL add `ssl://` to Your SMTP host address

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.zoho.com";
```

Comment: I have used tls:// this also works for me. By the way, Thank you.

Comment: @SajjadHossain yes, it depends on protocol Your mail-server work

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you, this solved the issue for me as well

Comment: @alex3410 Nice to hear it, mate! Have a great day! :)