# server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, server, smtp

I search all possible solutions to these problems and try but still not working.I contact my server which is webpandahost but they said it is working.

```
function send_email()
{
    $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'server.multimedia-street.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'bjmpncr@thefourpobu.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'admin123';
    $config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype']     = 'text';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('bjmpncr@thefourpobu.com', 'SJCDRRMO');
    $this->email->to('ruedastefano@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Password Reset');
    $this->email->message('We have reset your request. Your new password:  Do not reply to this email.');

    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
The IP address sending this message does not have a
550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from
550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
550 5.7.1 information. dn3si12455081pac.266 - gsmtp
```

Comment: if php reports success, then it's NOT a php problem. php's job is the equivalent of walking an envelope down to the street corner and tossing it into the mailbox. that's it. if the mail never gets to the destination, that's not php's problem, it's the postal service's. you have to go look at your mail server's logs.

Comment: How about viewing `$email->print_debugger();` even on success?  Does it give you the server chat?  Pass `$email->send(false);` beforehand. (From 3.0.6 manual).

Comment: @Progrock this is the output "The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."

Comment: I can't resolve your host: server.multimedia-street.com , is that the correct mail server?

Comment: @Progrock I find that in my cpanel in email settings and that is the outgoing server and its smtp port is 465. Is that the problem? if so should I use a mail() not smtp?

Comment: It may resolve on the server (perhaps it's private?).  Try php's `gethostbyname()` for that hostname on your server.

Comment: @Progrock haha sorry so what im gonna do for now?

Comment: You say the host name resolves to an IPV4 on the server.  Wild stab in the dark:  Try prefixing ssl:// to your smtp host.  As here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23234985/3392762

Comment: Another wild stab in the dark, In the manual there is an `smtp_crypto` config key.  Try `tls` or `ssl` as the value instead of the `ssl://` prefix.  Isn't the print_debugger giving you any more information?

Comment: @Progrock Same error :(

Comment: Sorry. I just don't know what to do :(

Comment: From information that you provided and removed earlier it looks as if  server.multimedia-street.com and thefourpobu.com resolve to the same IP.  Is this where the Php script is hosted?  Did you try codeigniter with the mail protocol (not smtp/codeigniters basic example)?  Which may go back to Marc B's top tip: check the mail logs on the server.  Did you try another to address?  Did you check spam folder?

Comment: @Progrock I also tried the mail protocol because smtp wont work but still mail also dont work. It says successfully send but no email received. also I check spam folder. This is my 2nd week for this problem and i search every solutions :( how can i check the mail logs on the server?

Comment: @Progrock I tried to add that line still nothing happens. same error :(

Comment: @MarcB i check the mail in my hosting. I have a message in inbox that said it is failed to send this is the error. The IP address sending this message does not have a
    550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from
    550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
    550 5.7.1 information. dn3si12455081pac.266 - gsmtp

Answer (score -4):

Try adding 'reply to' in the headers.

Or try this

```
$headers = "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;
$headers .= "Reply-To: Sender Name <sender@yahoo.com>\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Sender Name <sender@yahoo.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$headers  .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
if (mail('sendTo@email.com', 'Subject', 'message', $headers)) {
   "Mail successful.";  
}else{
   "Mail failed.";
}
```

Comment: Because servers tend to block or put it in the junk folder the emails that has no complete header. I got this similar problem and I did this to fix it. Nothing will be lost if you tried.

Comment: @FirstOne Sorry I just intend to comment but still can't. Tried to help by answering cause I had the same problem too.

Comment: where do I put reply to?

Comment: @TepTep add $this->email->reply_to($email);

Comment: @StephanSutter still not working. Now I get the error "The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method." Can someone help me please im getting crazy with this problem :(

Comment: @TepTep did you change the $email variable to your desired email?

Comment: @StephanSutter yup. or it should be initialized as variable $email?

Comment: @TepTep Not really. Did you try sending emails using mail() function?

Comment: @StephanSutter      I tried that but still nothing happens :(

Comment: @TepTep I updated my answer, that's what I'm using now.

Comment: @StephanSutter i use your code it says mail successful but still no email is received

Comment: So basically @StephanSutter, you've changed your answer, to suggest using php's native mail function (probably using the local transport).  Isn't this worlds away from the original problem?  There may be security concerns here.