# CodeIgniter - Unable to send email using PHP SMTP only in my own server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using CodeIgniter to send Email using this code:

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "mail.******.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
$config['smtp_user'] = "****@****.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "*****";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['send_multipart'] = \r\n;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

And it succeeds when I run on an online server (public hosting).

But I got the following error when I executed the code on my own server in local.

```
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
```

is there any error on my code or the server config?

Comment: Did you load `$this->load->library('email');`? Or check `smtp_port` as `587`

Comment: I put the library on the top

Answer (score 0):

Load library before initialize. May this help

```
 $this->load->library('email');

 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.******.com";
 $config['smtp_port'] = "25";  //465,587
 $config['smtp_user'] = "****@****.com";
 $config['smtp_pass'] = "*****";
 $config['smtp_timeout']='30';
 $config['charset']='utf-8';
 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
 $config['newline']  = "\r\n";

 $this->email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to your code, it is related to the configuration of your mail server! Or try changing the Port to 587!

[Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252547/unable-to-send-email-using-php-smtp-your-server-might-not-be-configured-to-send)

Comment: I've tried it and then I got this error:

SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol